# How to send a variable from Django template to view

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to send a number from the template page (.html) to views.py. For this, I did the following things:

urls.py

```
path('video/<int:value>', views.process_number, name='video_lab'),
```

.html

```
<div class="frame">  
    <span id="currentFrame">0</span>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" >
    <button id="stop_bttn_id" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="stop_bttn">Take Number</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function btn_click() {
        var x = document.getElementById('currentFrame').textContent
        fetch("{% url 'video_lab' value=x %}", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}'},
            body: 'true'
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
    }

    document.getElementById('stop_bttn_id').addEventListener('click', btn_click); 

</script>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def process_number(request, value: int):
    json_response = {....}
    return JsonResponse(json_response)
```

Here is the problem. If I directly send a number instead of variable, then the number can be sent to the views.py.

```
fetch("{% url 'video_lab' 5 %}"
```

However, if I try to send a variable, I get an error:

> NoReverseMatch at /video/
>
> Reverse for 'video_lab' with keyword arguments '{'value': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['video/(?P[^/]+)$']

I also tried:

```
fetch("{% url 'video_lab' x %}"
```

Although I did lots of research, I could not find any solution. Could anyone help me about it?

Best.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem. The variable should define on views.py and it should send to the template as a context element. However, I cannot change its value on the template part.